# Ошибка Unknown column 'extension' in 'where clause'

Tags: php

Подскажите в чём проблема, пожалуйста.

```
static function getCategoriesSelect_easyblog_category() 
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->setQuery("SELECT id, title, parent_id FROM #__easyblog_category  WHERE published = '1' AND `extension` IN ('com_content', 'system')");
    $rows = $db->loadAssocList();
    if (count($rows)) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $categories[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
        }
    }
    $categories = JoomlaParserHelper::getTreeArray($categories, 0, 'id');
    $categories = JoomlaParserHelper::treeSelect($categories);
    return $categories;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В таблице `#__easyblog_category` нет столбца `extension`

Comment: Да спасибо разобрался.